# .NET reflection - converting array-type property value into comma-separated string

Tags: .net, arrays, reflection

I am inspecting .NET objects using reflection to dump them to a log.

I've hit a snag - what if a property is an array type? I do get the `PropertyInfo` structure for that property, and I can see that the property is an array, and I can even get the value of that array property:

```
if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);
}
```

but now I'm stuck. When I look in the Visual Studio debugger, it shows as `int[3]` - so VS knows it's an array of three integers - but how can I convert this to a comma-separated string representing these three integers now?

I tried things like

```
string.Join(", ", value);
```

and others - but I'm always struggling with the fact that `value` is "dynamic", e.g. it could be a `int[]` or a `decimal[]` or even something else - so I cannot statically type it.... and if I don't type it, then the `string.Join()` returns strange results (definitely not what I'm looking for...)

Is there any clever way to convert this "array of something" to a comma-separated string without a lot of `if(...)` and `else { .... }` clauses??

Somehow I'm in a brain-freeze here right now - any ideas to thaw this freeze up would be most welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it seems like the easiest way around this problem would be to convert it to an `IEnumerable<object>`. Like this:

```
if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
    var values = (IEnumerable)propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);
    var stringValue = string.Join(", ", values.OfType<object>());
}
```

Although, because of [array covariance in c#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx), if `values` is an array of a *reference type*, it should be castable to `object[]`. For this case, you could use this instead:

```
if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
    var values = (IEnumerable)propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);
    var elementType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetElementType();
    if (elementType != null && !elementType.IsValueType)
    {
        var stringValue = string.Join(", ", (object[])values);
    }
    else
    {
        var stringValue = string.Join(", ", values.OfType<object>());
    }
}
```

Comment: `var stringValue = string.Join(", ", (object[])values);` will give an InvalidCastException for all value type arrays like `int[]` `double[]` etc.

Comment: @bitbonk You're right, I had neglected to specify that it would only work for reference types.

Comment: `PropertyType.IsArray` and `PropertyType.IsValueType` will never *both* be `true`, so the 2nd check is redundant.

Comment: +1 nice solution - however, in your second example, VS underlines the `OfType<object>` in red and mentions *Cannot Resolve Symbol 'OfType'*

Comment: @marc_s It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) provided by linq. make sure you put `using System.Linq` at the top of your file. Also, I forgot to cast the property value to `IEnumerable` in the beginning of my second example. That is key.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: thanks - I did have the `System.Linq` already in place - the cast to `(IEnumerable)` did the trick. Is there any benefit to using your second example over the first? What does the second handle that the first cannot?

Comment: @marc_s The first solution catches everything (or *bitbok*'s). The second solution *would* provide some marginal performance increase, since you're casting the whole array rather than each item in the array individually. I mostly wanted to include it in my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: `IEnumerable.Cast<object>` does try to cast directly, so if you'd use that instead of `IEnumerable.OfType<object>` the whole 2nd code block is never needed.

Comment: @bitbonk yes, `Cast<object>` does a direct cast of each object, but `(object[])` casts the *whole array*. So `values.Cast<object>` has the overhead of creating an iterator. Granted it's a small performance improvement, but it changes the limiting behavior from `O(n)` to `O(1)` for reference types.

Comment: No iterator will be created. `Cast<object>` will cast the *whole array*. That was my whole point. https://gist.github.com/bitbonk/5300330

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution that would work for all types of collections including arrays (`IEnumerable` is the least common base we can come up with):

`string.Join(", ", ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>().Select(i => i.ToString()));`